# Cannot load latest images to AVD

Tags: android, linux, emulation, android-virtual-device, fedora-25

I just installed Android Studio in Fedora (Because I have AMD processor and the AVD in Windows with AMD is painfully slow) and when I load images from Nougat to Lollipop, one of two things happen: Or I get no image in the emulator (Nougat, Marshmallow), or every process stops (Maps has stopped, Google has stopped, Dialer has stopped, and so on).

So, my solution was loading KitKat. I alway get a Warning: Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86 emulation: SSSE3
Hardware-accelerated emulation may not work properly! Regardless of the image version (x86 only), and if I try to load any x86_64, SSS4.1, etc.  (This, I guess, simply because my processor cannot handle those instructions).

**My question is:** what can be causing that problem with those specific images? Why does KitKat work? I've also tried using software renderer, instead of hardware.

**My specs:** AMD Phenom XII processor, 6GB RAM, Fedora 25 64bits (I tried installing in Ubuntu, but many problems regarding some libraries), ATI HD 6800.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without providing any code would be really difficult to help you.

Comment: the question is why don't you use an android emulator like genymotion, bluestacks, ...?

Comment: @SsouLless There's really no code to show. The problem appears at the very moment I boot AVD. No need to load any apk.

Comment: @Zamani I have heard of Genymotion, but AFAIK it doesn't work in Windows 10,also, it appears that's mandatory to pay. I'll check Bluestacks; that one I didn't know of.  Thanks.